# How to compare TKeyHash with TAddress? [SmartPy]

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, address, key-hash

I am writing a smart contract which allows the delegate to be changed. I also want incoming payments to be permissioned. Ideally, I want to update the incoming payment whitelist with the baker's address at the same time the delegate is changed. But changing the delegate requires a `TKeyHash` while `sp.sender` is of type `TAddress`.

How can I compare, or convert, a `TKeyHash` to `TAddress` and the reverse?

I have tried casting with `sp.address(baker_key_hash)` or `sp.key_hash(baker_address)` but that gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a `key_hash` to a `contract` and then a `contract` to an `address`.

```
sp.to_address(sp.implicit_account(my_key_hash))
```

Relevant documentation:

https://smartpy.io/docs/types/contracts_addresses#cast-key_hash-to-a-typed-contract

https://smartpy.io/docs/types/contracts_addresses#convert-contract-to-address

Converting from an `address` to a `key_hash` is not possible. For an example why, a `KT1...` `address` does not have a corresponding `key_hash`.

Comment: Thank you. But that only answers half the question. What about the reverse? Is there a way to convert from `TAddress` to `TKeyHash`?

Comment: @BakeꜩforMe, no. Remark that it wouldn’t be sound, KT1… addresses don’t correspond to key hashes.